# My Energy Usage Test in Instrument show nothing (iOS)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, instruments

I am testing my app's energy usage with `Instrument's` Energy Usage feature.

However when i test my app , that Energy Usage bar doesn't show anything like following pic.

[image]

What does it's mean?

That's mean my app doesn't use energy too much?

I am very new to Energy Testing.
I am testing my app with iPad2.

Please explain me.
Thanks.